# No GUI on fresh project

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

On Spring Boot Initializr I setup a project with `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-admin-starter-server`, but when run it produces no GUI on `localhost:8080`. The log shows a message related to Thymeleaf templates. Is it related? How can I make this thing work?

```
Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
```

**Bootstrap class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAdminServer
public class SbasApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SbasApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>br.com.cesan</groupId>
<artifactId>sbas</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>sbas</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-boot-admin.version>2.0.2</spring-boot-admin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-admin.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Is this actually a fresh project?  You seem to have added a couple of things: `@EnableAdminServer`, `reactive-streams`

Comment: I got the GUI by adding the `@EnableAdminServer` to a fresh project with the starters you indicated.  Launched with `./mvnw clean spring-boot:run`

Comment: I also have this warning about "Cannot find template location: ..." but everything works fine with pom from the question. Maybe your application failed to start? Maybe port is busy, or smth else ?